# determine p(c) using synthetic division and remainder theorem

Tags: polynomials

Use synthetic division and the Remainder Theorem to evaluate (), where

p(x)= $x^4 + 7x^3 +5x^2+ 40x +41$, c = -7.

the quotient is ?, the remainder is ? P(c) = ?

I was able to determine that the quotient is $x^3+5x+5$ and the remainder is 6. But what is p(c)?

Comment: $p(c)$ is the remainder (when dividing by $(x-c)$).

Comment: if i let p(c) = 6/(x+7), webwork says that the answer isn't a number (it looks like a formula that returns a number)

Comment: $p(c)$ is a number. Using synthetic division you   find $Q(x)$ (the quotient) and $R$ (the remainder) with $p(x)=Q(x)\cdot(x-c)+R$. The Remainder theorem states $R=p(c)$. (You could just substitute $-7$ for $x$ in $p(x)$ to find $p(c)$, but that's more work than needed here.)